# What is the formula to perspective projection?

Tags: projection-matrices

What is the formula to perspective projection?

Is:

(p * cameraFocal) / pz

or: p * (cameraFocal / pz)

Comment: Some context would help, is this an optics question? Some example matrices would be helpful. I don't know what any of those symbols mean, particularly p and pz. There's also a physics stack exchange, maybe that would be more helpful?

Comment: Is the context of computer graphics.

P is x or y position, pz is z position.

In my rendering wireframe software this formula seems to have fixed a bug that happened when the object was far away, the correctly formula in this case is first.

Comment: Convert to simple homogeneous coordinates first: $x' = xd / (x+d), y' = yd / (y+d), z' = 0$ where $d>0$. And $w' = z/d+w$

Comment: ............... w?

Comment: If all of those values are scalars (numbers), then the two expressions that you have are completely equivalent.